# Celery: Executing a task after another task, but return the result of the first task

Tags: python, celery

Sometimes I need to run task B after task A, but return the result of task A. Looking at the docs, I have tried to ([Avoid launching synchronous subtasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks))

So I would use a chain, like this:

```
@celery.task
def A():
    return 5

@celery.task
def B():
    return 2

def do_all():
    chain = A.s() | B.s()
    chain()
    return result_of_A
```

But this would not work. In my case I need:

- B does not have any parameter. It does not accept the result of A
- B must be executed *after* A completes
- I do not need to wait for B to complete, and I do not need its result (B must be async?)
- How do I return the result of A in do_all? (A must be sync?)

Is it possible to implement this with chains or any other subtasks primitives?

Answer (score 0):

I can't noodle a way to do this with primitives; there probably is one.  But a different approach that would work is, use the `on_success` or `after_return` handler in task A to initiate task B.  If you also use the `ignore_result` option, then the invocation of task B would be truly fire-and-forget.